# How do I dynamically change class through an addClass() function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've been trying to write a function that can take a value and add it to an elements class. Something like this:

```
var changeClass = function(newClass){ 
  $("div").removeClass().addClass(newClass);
};

changeClass(red);
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: You are using `red` as if it was a variable. Don't you mean `changeClass("red")` ?

Comment: Unless you plan on accessing the CSS `sheets` collection and dynamically creating new styles, this is not possible.  Instead, pre-make your classes and add/remove them as necessary. If you truly need a dynamic adjustment, make the change to the CSS directly, not the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like below:-

```js
var changeClass = function(newClass){ 
  $("div").removeClass().addClass(newClass); // single line to remove class+add new class
};
$(document).ready(function(){
  changeClass("red"); // call function with string value
});
```

```css
.green{
  background:green;
  color:white;
}

.red{
  background:red;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="green">div1</div><br>
<div class="green">div2</div><br>
<div class="green">div3</div><br>
<div class="green">div4</div><br>
<div class="green">div5</div><br>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are trying to replace all classes on all `div`s... you pretty much had it.

```
var changeClass = function(newClass){ 
  $("div").removeClass()
  $("div").addClass(newClass);
};

var red = "red" // I'm guessing this is what you want?
changeClass(red);
```

Comment: Actually, if the OP had multiple `div`, then the code would still work. The outcome would be that all of the `div` in the page would have their class replaced by `red`, which may (or may not) be expected.

Comment: You're right, I've changed my answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any way of making the value a string within the function?

Comment: if you call changeClass with `red`, you're going to get a ReferenceError. It needs to be a string, or `red` needs to be a declared variable.

Comment: I see! Thanks, didn't realise I could pass a string through. 
@MatiasCicero

Thanks to you both!